# How to detect if only part of the properties is set?

Tags: java, combinatorics

```
String a = "1";
String b;
...
String n = "100";
```

How can I check if none or all of the properties have been set?

I want to get "valid" if a..n all properties are set, and also "valid" if none if them are set. But "invalid" if only partially set.

How can this be solved? Of course I could write endless boolean statements like

`(a != null && b != null & .. & n != null) || (a == null && b == null & .. & n == null)`

But there must be a better way.

Comment: Check out java.util.Map

Comment: If you want to stick with regular java variables, you have to use reflection: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a sample class

```
public class SampleClass {    

    private String a, b, c, d, e, f;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public String getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(String d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public String getE() {
        return e;
    }

    public void setE(String e) {
        this.e = e;
    }

    public String getF() {
        return f;
    }

    public void setF(String f) {
        this.f = f;
    }

}
```

you can get the Java Bean information using the `java.beans.Introspector`

```
import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import org.junit.Test;

public class IntrospectorTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws IntrospectionException, IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        SampleClass sampleClass = new SampleClass();

        sampleClass.setA("value for a");
        sampleClass.setB("value for b");
        sampleClass.setC("value for c");
        sampleClass.setD("value for d");
        sampleClass.setE("value for e");
        sampleClass.setF("value for f");

        int withValue = 0;

        PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors = Introspector.getBeanInfo(SampleClass.class, Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors();

        for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : descriptors) {
            Object value = new PropertyDescriptor(propertyDescriptor.getName(), SampleClass.class).getReadMethod().invoke(sampleClass);
            if (value!=null) {
                withValue++;
                System.out.println(propertyDescriptor.getName() + ": " + value);    
            }
        }

        if (descriptors.length == withValue || withValue == 0) {
            System.out.println("valid");
        }else{
            System.err.println("Invalid!!");
        }
    }
}
```

and voila!

Pay atention at this line

```
Introspector.getBeanInfo(SampleClass.class, Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors();
```

if you call the `getBeanInfo` method with your class as one and only parameter the `Introspector` will return all the Property Descriptors in the class hierarchy, so you can call the method with an optional stop class where the `Introspector` stops reading the Property Descriptors.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map then iterate over it to check if any of the value is null and set status accordingly.

You can also try with this: Collections.frequency(map.values(), null) == map.size()